# How can I check the user command history in Unix?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, terminal, history

I know the 'history' command give me a list of the commands I have typed into the Unix terminal.

How do I see the command history for all of the users currently logged onto the system?

Comment: Not programming related. I suggest you ask on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: There is no standard-tool to get the information, so I think it is programming (at least in the sense of 'scripting') - related.

Answer (score 11):

You get a list of currently logged in users in `/var/run/utmp` (see `man 5 utmp`). The history is stored in ~/.history or for bash user in ~/.bash_history. Other shells may use other history files, so it's not that easy to get really all information.

Furthermore, if a user is logged in multiple times, the .bash_history file is not always reliable.

To read the `utmp` file there is a "frontend" called `who`, so you could also write a shell-script to iterate over the currently logged in users.

Comment: The current history is held in memory. The history file only shows what was written using `history -a` or similar or when a user exits the shell.

Comment: Note that the file names given in this answer are merely the defaults. Each user could have set his own location (see Joy's answer). If a user is using different shells, they could conceivably store their histories in different, non-default locations (e.g. ~/mybashhist, ~/histories/ksh or somesuch). Also, be aware that peeking user data like that might have legal implications.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo $HISTFILE
```

Then view that file.

Comment: This works only if you have previously sourced that user's environment (as he might have set `HISTFILE` to something else).